# change initialisation options programmatically

Tags: javascript, i18next

I'm using the javascript-library `i18next` for multi-language support.

I can set options like the fallback-Language at initialisation:

```
i18n.init(
    {   lng: "de",
        fallbackLng: ["en", "fr"],
    });
```

However, I need to be able to change these options programatically any time after initialisation.

I can change the language by calling `i18next.setLng("en");`, but is there a way to modify the fallback-languages and other options like `sendMissing`?

Comment: There is i18n.options that might work. Don't know if it will. I don't use i18n. I just looked at the source. You could just go i18n.options["fallbacking"] = ["en", "fr"], but you'll probably have to call init any way because options come from a closure.

Comment: Your best bet would be to save the options in a variable then just modify them before you re-init.

Comment: By the way setLng just calls the init function.

Comment: @QuentinEngles well, if `setLng` internally calls the init-function, it makes no sense for me to use it. I can call the init-function myself and can reset all options. I thought `setLng` might be a more efficient way. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options are saved in a closure so they are common to all init settings.
The `setLng` function just calls the `init function` as well.

So it's best if you just call the `init function` to apply new options. It shouldn't cause to much overhead in speed, and time because those options are saved in a closure and i18n only has one instance, any way.